# Why doesn't Picker onTap and onChange work together?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-picker

I have a picker (segmented). I need onTap and onChange both on it. onTap works but onChange doesn't work. If I remove tap, just the onChange code works.

I need both because I am prefilling question.answer onAppear and hence onChange is triggered when prefilling. I need to know when user taps on segmented control.

Code is something like this:

```
Picker("", selection: question.answer) {
        ForEach(yesNoOptions, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture(perform: {
        //do something
    })
    .onChange(of: question.answer.wrappedValue, perform: { newValue in
        // do something
    })
    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
```

Comment: Actually you don't need both. Create a flag `isPrefilling` which is set and reset in `onAppear`. In `onChange` do nothing when `isPrefilling` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a `tag` to each option in your segmented picker. Otherwise SwiftUI won't know what option in the picker corresponds to which value and then won't be able to update the selection value.
To do that simply add the `.tag(...)` modifier to your Text views in the picker like so:

```
Picker("", selection: question.answer) {
    ForEach(yesNoOptions, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
            .tag($0) // <--- indicates which value this picker option relates to
    }
}
```

Depending on what data type you use for `answer`, you might need to also make it conform to `Hashable`, otherwise you will get a compiler error.

Comment: Can you please eloborate? I need to how an alert on first tap of picker segment. But I need onChange to update the selected answer. I am not sure how tag is going to help.

Comment: Ask yourself this, if the user selects `Text($0)` via the picker, how does the picker actually know what value to store in `question.answer`? SwiftUI only sees a Text view. You need to tell it what value each selection option refers to. For that you use `.tag()`. Once you have that, SwiftUI will see "ah, the user selected that view, which correlates to that value, so I will take that value and store it in the answer". And *then*, as the value of the answer changes, you will get an event in `onChange()`.